# Fecha de nacimiento a idioma humano PostgresSql

Tags: postgresql

Buen día a todos, agradezco el tiempo que se toman en leer mi inquietud.

Estoy tratando de elaborar un query en donde este calcula la edad de una persona pero a idioma humano, me explico tenemos la fecha de nacimiento (Y-m-d) 1997-04-29  idioma humano seria : 24 años 3 meses y 18 días, esto es posible hacerlo directamente en postgretSql sin recurrir al backend ?, o si tienen algún foro relacionado les agradecería mucho, he buscado mucho en google y recurro a ustedes como ultimo recurso, no se si tal vez este buscando mal o esto no sea posible.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @Alfabravo podrías indicarme como buscar lo que estoy tratando de hacer, es algo similar a lo que hace laravel con el diffForHumans();

Comment: Las bases de datos no suelen tener esa funcionalidad.. eso no quiere decir que no puedas hacer una funcion que devuelva eso....

Comment: @gbianchi, en PL/SQL de Oracle yo hice esa funcionalidad una vez, imagino que postgre tenga un equivalente a PL/SQL

Comment: @CamiloMancipe, aqui te dejo un ejemplo hecho en c++, pero haciendo el proceso inverso, es decir convertir de palabras a numero, lo que pides se parece bastante a esto, de hecho es casi lo mismo

Comment: Muchas gracias, les agradezco un montón :) son lo mejores

Answer (score 2):

En Postgresql puedes usar las funciones:

- age(timestamp, timestamp): resta dos fechas retornando la diferencia en años, meses y días.
- age(timestamp): resta la fecha pasada como parámetro a la fecha actual retornando la diferencia en años, meses y días.

[Funciones Date/Time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

```
SELECT age(current_date, '1997-04-29');

ó

SELECT age(timestamp '1997-04-29');
```

Resultado: "24 years 3 mons 20 days"

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, al parecer no busque lo suficiente, soy nuevo con postgres

Comment: De nada @CamiloMancipe!